# How to Add an Icon into an Entry in GTK#?

Tags: gtk#

How to add primary and secondary icon to an Entry in GTK#? I can't find some method like Entry.setIconFromStock(EntryIconPosition, Stock) in java-gnome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Icons in entries were supported starting in GTK 2.16. As you can see [on the GTK language bindings page](http://www.gtk.org/language-bindings.php), the C# binding only supports up to 2.12.

Answer (score 2):

You should write `set_icon_from_stock` instead of `setIconFromStock`.
Here is a sample :

```
entry = gtk.Entry()
entry.set_icon_from_stock(1, gtk.STOCK_FIND)
```

Comment: I even can't find class or namespace gtk, there's only Gtk. Are you sure this is Gtk#? I mean, not PyGTK?